# What metrics does CSS use when not specifying it when changing size?

Tags: html, css, node.js, jsx

I noticed when I use style in div or any other elements, without specifying size metrics.

It uses one sizing.

But when I use class and also do not specify metrics of size then it uses completely other metric.

For instance, I have image element which height and width was set to 50

```
<img src={photo} style={{width: 50, height :50}} />
```

And then I have another image for which height and width were set to 50 as well but through className

```
<img src={photo} className="photo" /> 

.photo {
    height: 50;
    width: 50;
}
```

But sizes are different here, could anyone explain me why sizes are different?

And how do I use this size from `style={{width: 50, height :50}}` in className ?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you have to add unit with size eg: `px`, `%`, `em`, `rem` etc. Only if the value is 0, the unit can be omitted. For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Soluation:

```
  <img src={photo} className="photo" /> 

  .photo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
  }
```

Comment: But could please tell, 50 without unit in style  its equals to 50px in className then ?

Comment: Yes, in JSX inline style and `width="" and height=""` attribute `px` will automatically apply.

Comment: `<img src={photo} style={{width: 50, height :50}} />` = `widht: 50px` `height: 50px` also same for `<img src={photo} width="50" height="50"/>`